# Can Datagrip do cross DB queries/joins?

Tags: datagrip

I'm looking to use DG to join data from Snowflake and Impala or Hadoop. I can't see how I can do this as the job is sent to the DB to run the query. Is there any work arounds or hold the data/table in memory to use across sessions?

Thanks

testing DB connections

Comment: I believe there isn't a way. [There's an issue created for it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8805) but seems like it won't be getting implemented anytime soon...

Comment: Have you tried [Copy to Database...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/tables-copy.html) feature?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to create tables from the result/tables of the other databases. And then `JOIN` with these tables.

Please see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/tables-copy.html